# How cloudwatch logging works with auto scaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Say I set up aws cloudwatch logging on an ec2 instance to centralize logs from various files. If I have auto-scaling and a new machine gets started up due to high traffic, will the new copied machine start sending logs then too? Does logging work with auto-scale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the CloudWatch Logs agent is installed and configured on the AMI that is used for auto-scaling, the logs for the new instance(s) will be sent to CloudWatch. You can use the Instance ID when configuring the CloudWatch Logs agent to be able to identify which instance originated the event in the logs.

Also, make sure the instances have the necessary [IAM role policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html) to publish the logs to CloudWatch.